# Does sniping guards from a building work?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I was on a high ledge or a building and I shot a guard with an arrow, will I get caught? I mean I know it all depends on if you are detected or not but does it injure the guards and they will not see you?

Comment: What usually happens when you attack someone with a bow?  The same thing will happen when you attack a guard.

Comment: What will happen if I have like an in insane skill level in sneak

Comment: Why would you think it would not hurt somebody if they were shot from a roof?

Comment: I don't see how this differs from understanding the stealth mechanics in the first place.

Comment: What I mean is, will I get detected if I hav a lot of skill and will I do some major damage to him

Answer (score 3):

You won't do more damage shooting from a roof compared to shooting from anywhere else, elevation is not a factor in damage calculations. It will be easier to stay undetected if you are in a location that is unreachable by your victim, but regular rules apply, if you are heavily illuminated or have low sneak skill then you will likely get detected.

Comment: Thanks just checking if it'll work. I usually use daggers anyway and bows for long distance